# I'm having an issuse with my concurrent transaction query

Tags: sql, concurrency, transactions

I have written the following query for concurrent transaction

```
Select * from Accounts
-- Transfer $ 100 from Mark to Mary

Begin Try 
    Begin Transaction
    update Accounts Set Balance = Balance=100 Where ID= 1
    update accounts set balance = balance=100 Where ID = 2
    Commit Transaction
    Print ' Transaction Committed '
End Try 
Begin CATCH
    Rollback Transaction
    Print ' Transaction Rolled back '
End CATCH
```

Comment: You have an issue.  Do you have a question?

Comment: What am I missing here? I have tried several times to change up the spelling and or the pronunciation in this query to see if that's where the problem lies unfortunately, much to my dismay it's not case sensitive  so that's not the problem. My SQL keeps telling me that I have errors.